# What is the use of DISPOSE method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class CleanClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected override void Finalize()
    {
        **Dispose();**
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation of `IDisposable` is not correct according to the documentation on how to implement the interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is the documentation not clear?

Comment: @PraveenSinghBaghel Are you overriding `finalizer` to handle unmanaged resources ?

Answer (score 2):

It is used to free `unmanaged` resources like files, database connectionsetc. at any time.

You need to explicitly call `Dispose` on any objects that implement `IDisposable`. If you use the [using()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) {} code construct the compiler will automatically call Dispose at the end of the using block.

**UPDATE** 
Please read this, i could provide a shorter version but i think you should read this to understand system resource management better .

[Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

## **Dispose()**

> This method permanently removes any resource ((un)managed) from memory for
> cleanup and the resource no longer exists for any further processing.

## [Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Dispose method is using to remove unmanagement resources, such as db connection, file handles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Dispose method is, `Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources`. For more detials : [Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Dispose() method is used to rid the state of an object. You can find more information on this over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).